# How to decode a base64 string image into byte array and store it as blob type in database?

Tags: java, android

I have a Base64 string image which is stored in my mobile database. I want to convert it into blob type and save it in database.

I have`String base64Image="iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAACgCAYAAADzcGmMAAAACSV...";`

This is what I tried.

```
 byte[] byteImage=org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(befImage.getBytes());

 json.put("during_unloading_photo", byteImage);
```

where json is my JSONObject and during_unloading_photo is the column name which is blob type.I am not able to store the byte array ie byteImage as blob type in my data base.

Comment: So, do you get any errors? putting binary data into something called `json` seems wrong. How does `json` get stored in the database?

Comment: My requirement is to send the details about the customer through mobile which will be automatically synced from mobile database to main database .. I am able to sync all the details except the customers photo..which is stored in my mobile database as base64 string..

Answer (score 0):

so you have a table created by query like that:

```
query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + ImageTableName + " ("
                        + Id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                        + ImageUrlName + " TEXT, "
                        + ImageContentName + " BLOB );";
                db.execSQL(query);
```

and when you need to update image in db you do it like this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(DbUtil.ImageContentName, byteImage);

int rowCount = context.getContentResolver().update(DbUtil.ContentUriImage, values, ImageUrlName + "=?", whereArgs);
```

it's quite simple.

Comment: thank you @anil.. The function which I have used to decode the base64 string to byte array.. Is it the right one ??

Comment: And I have already stored the captured image as base64 String in my mobile database.. I need to sync the image ie base64 string to main database  where it will b stored as blob type.

Comment: @Thejas, you can check whether it is the right function by comparing its results to what you expect to get after decoding.